# ASP.NET GridView can`t find properties

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an ObjectDataSource, bind to static class state with all methods: select, update, insert, delete to work with instances of serviceRecord class. It looks fine. But when I bind it with GridView, GridView can`t find any serviceRecord property and auto generate columns. Without auto generation i have an exception: HttpException (0x80004005): A field or property with the name 'serviceStart' was not found on the selected data source.

```
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ServiceRecordsDataSource" runat="server" 
                DataObjectTypeName="LaretsState.serviceRecord" TypeName="LaretsState.state"
                DeleteMethod="deleteRecord" InsertMethod="addRecord" 
                SelectMethod="getRecords" UpdateMethod="updateRecord" >
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 ObjectDataSourceId ="ServiceRecordsDataSource" DataSourceID="ServiceRecordsDataSource">

                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="serviceStart" DataFormatString="dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm" HeaderText="Date and time of service" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="serviceDuration" DataFormatString="mm" HeaderText="Duration" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="creationTime" DataFormatString="dd.MM.yyyy hh.mm" HeaderText="Creation time" />
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
```

The classes are:

```
        namespace LaretsState
    {

        public static class state
        {

            public static actualState actualState
            { get { return new actualState(getActualState(), getNextRecord()); } }

            private static List<serviceRecord> _plan = new List<serviceRecord>();

            static state() { }

            public static List<serviceRecord> getRecords()
            {
                return _plan;
            }

            public static void updateRecord(serviceRecord record)
            {
                serviceRecord newRecord = record;
                lock (_plan)
                {
                    serviceRecord oldRecord = _plan.Where(r=> r.id== record.id).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (oldRecord == null)
                    { throw new ArgumentException("В плане отсутствует запись с id " + record.id, "recordid"); }

                    var ColissionRecords = GetCollisionRecords(newRecord);

                    if (ColissionRecords.Count() > 1 ||
                        ColissionRecords.Count() == 1 && !ColissionRecords.Contains(oldRecord))
                    { throw new Exception("На предложенное время уже запланировано обслуживание"); }

                    oldRecord = newRecord;
                    //_plan.Remove(oldRecord);
                    //_plan.Add(newRecord);
                }
            }

            public static void deleteRecord(serviceRecord record)
            {
                _plan.Remove(record);
            }

            public static void addRecord(serviceRecord record)
            {
                lock (_plan)
                {
                    var ColissionRecords = GetCollisionRecords(record);

                    if (ColissionRecords.Count() > 1 )
                    { throw new Exception("На предложенное время уже запланировано обслуживание"); }

                    _plan.Add(record);
                }
            }

            private static List<serviceRecord> GetCollisionRecords (serviceRecord record)
            {
                return _plan.Where(r => r.serviceStart <= record.serviceStart.Add(record.serviceDuration)
                        && r.serviceStart.Add(r.serviceDuration) > record.serviceStart).ToList();
            }

            private static serviceRecord getNextRecord()
            {
                DateTime nowdate = DateTime.Now;

                if (_plan.Count() == 0) return null;

                return _plan
                    .Where(r => r.serviceStart > nowdate)
                    .OrderBy(r => r.serviceStart)
                    .First();
            }

            private static serviceState getActualState()
            {
                DateTime nowDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                var recordsInProgress = _plan.Where(r => r.serviceStart <= nowDateTime 
                    && r.serviceStart.Add(r.serviceDuration) > nowDateTime).Count();

                if (recordsInProgress >0)
                { return serviceState.OnService; }
                else
                { return serviceState.Normal; }
            }
    }
        }

}


    namespace LaretsState
{
    [DataContract]
    public class serviceRecord
    {
        private static int lastid = 0;
    [DataMember]
    public  DateTime serviceStart;
    [DataMember]
    public  TimeSpan serviceDuration;
    [DataMember]
    public readonly DateTime creationTime;
    [DataMember]
    public readonly int id;

    public serviceRecord (DateTime serviceStart, TimeSpan serviceDuration)
        :this()
    {
        this.serviceStart = serviceStart;
        this.serviceDuration = serviceDuration;
    }

    public serviceRecord()
    {
        this.creationTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.id = ++lastid;
    }
    }
}
```

Is it somthing wrong with a classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found! In serviceRecord class I must use properties, not fields:

```
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime serviceStart { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public  TimeSpan serviceDuration { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime creationTime { get;}
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get;}
```